# How can I sort Images ? in Matlab

Tags: image, matlab

I have a vector

```
norma = [1.087,0.047,0,0.35];
```

And I have several frames from a video. Ex.

```
pill(:,:,:,48);
pill(:,:,:,49);
pill(:,:,:,50);
pill(:,:,:,51);
```

What I want is to "attach" each frame to each element from `norma` vector, and then sort the images, by sorting `norma` vector in ascending way.

How can I do this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```
[sortednorma, idx] = sort(norma);
pill = pill(:,:,:,idx);
```